# How can I scale arrowheads according to arrow length?

Tags: plotting, functions

I am looking for a solution to the arrowheads have different sizes for each arrow, but I am doing something wrong and I am not finding the error.
I think it should be obvious, but I am blind.

```
w = 1/2 (4 - x)^2;   
divisions = 20;  

CargDist = Plot[
  w, {x, 0, 4},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  PlotRange -> {{-.25, 4}, {-1.5, 8}},
  Epilog -> {Thickness[.004], 
    Arrowheads[#]& /@ Subdivide [0.04, .02, divisions],
    Arrow[({{#1, (1/2)(4 - #1)^2}, {#1, 0}}&) /@ Subdivide[0, 3.2, divisions]],
    EdgeForm[Thick],
    Opacity[0.2],
    Gray,
    Rectangle[{0, -1}, {4, 0}]}]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really just need a better scaling function for the arrowheads. Also, you must scale each arrowhead separately.

```
w[x_] := 1/2 (4 - x)^2
With[{divisions = 20},
  Plot[w[x], {x, 0, 4},
    PlotStyle -> Red,
    PlotRange -> {{-.25, 4}, {-1.5, 8}},
    ImageSize -> 500,
    Epilog ->
      {Thickness[.004],
       Table[
         {Arrowheads[.02 w[u]^.5], 
          Arrow[{{u, w[u]}, {u, 0}}]}, {u, Subdivide[0, 3.2, divisions]}],
       EdgeForm[Thick], Opacity[0.2], Gray, Rectangle[{0, -1}, {4, 0}]} ]]
```

[image: plot]

Also note that I did not use a pure function. It is easier to tackle this problem by giving `w` a conventional function definition.

Comment: Seems to me very interesting the proposal on the use of the function of pure in `Arrowheads[.02 w[u]^.5]`. I had not imagined this possibility.